# Is the base case being returned in this recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I understand why the first code block works because there is a base case which returns.
In the second code block there is no explicit return for the base case and only an *if* statement to check if the node exists, and I am confused how recursion exactly works there.

```
 class Solution:
        def inorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
            result = []
            def dfs(node):
                if not node: return
                dfs(node.left)
                result.append(node.val)
                dfs(node.right)
            dfs(root)
        return result



class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
        result = []
        def dfs(node):
            if node:
             dfs(node.left)
             result.append(node.val)
             dfs(node.right)
        dfs(root)
        return result
```

Comment: it will return with a value of `None` if there is no return value specified.

Comment: One of the largest cause of mistakes in python code is the fact that python functions silently return `None` when they can't reach an explicit `return` statement. In this case, this fact is used on purpose.